# Determine a polynom $P(x)\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ of degree $2$ such that $P(2)=0$ and $P(-i)=3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

I think the correct answer is that it is impossible to write a real polynom having the prescribed characteristics. In fact, in order for $2$ and $-i$ to be roots and for the polynom to have real coefficients, also the conjugate of $x-i$ needs to be a root, so that:
\begin{equation}
P(x)=(x-2)(x-i)(x+i)Q(x)
\end{equation}
So the miniumum degree of $P$ is $3$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: $P(-i)=3$ so $-i$ is *not* a root.

Comment: Note that $i$ isn't a root

Comment: set $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong in saying that there is no such polynomial, note that $i$ is no root of $P$.

Let $P \in \mathbf R[X]$ with $P(-i) = 3$, then $-i$ is a root of $Q := P - 3$, therefore $i$ is also a root of $Q$, hence $Q$ has to be a multiple of $x^2 + 1$. As $Q$ is of degree 2, $Q(x) = a(x^2 + 1)$ for $a \in \mathbf R$. This gives 
$$ P(x) = a(x^2 + 1) + 3 $$
With $$0= P(2) = 5a + 3 \iff a = -\frac 35$$
we get 
$$ P(x) = -\frac 35(x^2 + 1) + 3. $$

Answer (score 0):

No, the minimum degree is not $3$, and there *is* indeed such a real polynomial. We may take
$$
P(x)=-\frac{3}{5}(x-2)(x+2),
$$
which satisfies $P(2)=0$ and $P(-i)=3$, because $-\frac{3}{5}(-i-2)(-i+2)=3$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x) = a(x^2 + 1) + 3\\
P(2) = 5a + 3=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ has degree $2$, and $P(2)=0, P(-i)=3$, then 
$$
P(X)=a(X-2)(X-b)=a[X^2-(b+2)X+2b],
$$ 
where $a$ and $b$ are such that $a, a(b+2), ab \in \mathbb{R}$, with $a\ne 0$.
Since
$$
3=P(-i)=a[-1+(b+2)i+2b]=-a+2ab+a(b+2)i
$$
we have 
$$
-a+2ab=3,\quad a(b+2)=0
$$
and deduce that $b=-2$ because $a\ne 0$, and therefore $a=-3/5$.

Thus
$$
P(X)=-\dfrac35(X-2)(X+2)=\dfrac{12}{5}-\dfrac{3}{5}X^2.
$$